# scanf() ждет ввода

Tags: c

Подскажите пожалуйста, какое условие придумать для моего алгоритма? Мне нужно в течение нескольких секунд ждать ввода цифры; если цифра была введена, то она идет в `switch` в `case 1:`. Если через это время никакой цифры `scanf()` не получил, то он должен уходить в `default:`.

Моя проблема заключается в том, что когда я нажимаю `1` , то `case 1:` уходит в бесконечный цикл,т.е. `break;` не срабатывает. Но какое условие нужно, чтобы мой `while()` ждал `scanf()` постоянно.

```
while(p.satiety!=0)
{
        printf("Satiety: %d\n",p.satiety);
        printf("Action: \n");

       if(poll(&mypoll,1,2000))
       {
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        }

  else{
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            Feed(&p);
            break;
        default:
            waitFor(2);
            Hungry(&p);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Я работаю на Linux, подозреваю, что `scanf()` не может работать с моим таймером. Тогда я могу использовать `getch()`(вставляю доп.функция,так как в Linux его нет). Но `switch()` не входит в мой `case 32:` (32-аски код пробела). Помогите решить проблему

Comment: Попробуйте использовать <time.h> и функцию time(NULL) оттуда.

Comment: @IvanMakarov Д как бы сам `poll` работает. Не работает условие

Comment: Что значит "нажимаю цифру 1"? По умолчанию, терминал не будет ничего передавать для чтения через `scanf`, пока не нажат Enter в конце строки.

Comment: Вы хотите getch() с timeout на Linux реализовать? 1- [выключите ICANON режим с помощью tcsetattr()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23035044/4279), чтобы не ждать новой строки в терминале для получения ввода 2- затем можно [использовать API типа  select()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/448982/4279), чтобы timeout реализовать 3- если что-то сложнее хотите, то посмотрите не имеет ли смысл [ncurses библиотеку использовать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/449151/4279) в вашем случае, чтобы её не создавать самостоятельно по кускам.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, тут может быть много решений, но если требуется использовать именно `scanf` (или другие "высокоуровневые" функции работы с `FILE *`) и не хочется менять ICANON дисциплину ввода или тем более использовать неблокирующий файловый дескриптор, то видимо наиболее очевидным решением является использование функции `alarm()`, которая запускает таймер и по его истечении программа получает сигнал `SIGALRM`, который прерывает чтение.

Вот пример, как можно реализовать подобный "scanf" для чтения одного целого числа (реализовать полноценный scanf с таймаутом ненамного сложнее)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void alahdr (int sig) {} // обработчик сигнала

int
time_scanfi(int sec, int *pv)
{
  signal(SIGALRM, alahdr); 
  siginterrupt(SIGALRM, 1); // требуется прервать системный вызов 
  alarm(sec);               // установим таймаут
  errno = 0;
  int res = scanf("%d", pv);
  if (errno == EINTR)       // таймер сработал, обработчик перехватил сигнал
    tcflush(fileno(stdin), TCIFLUSH); // сбросим возможно введенные, но еще не прочитанные в FILE *stdin данные 
  alarm(0);                 // остановим таймер 
  return res;
}
```

Вот пример тестовой программы

```
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int v, go = 1;

  while (go) {
    fputs("Enter val: ", stdout); fflush(stdout);

    int res = time_scanfi(2, &v);
    if (res == EOF) {
      if (errno == EINTR) {
        puts("Timeout");
        continue;
      } else {
        perror("stdin");
        break;
      }
    } else if (res == 1)
      printf("read %d\n", v);
    else {
      puts("skip invalid input");
      int c;
      while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        if (c == EOF) {
          go = 0;
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Скорее всего это формальный ответ, как можно использовать упомянутый в вопросе scanf,  вместе с таймаутом.
Дело в том, что scanf в ICANON режиме потока вводит данные по нажатию Enter, а по данному ТС описанию можно предположить, что ему как раз хочется читать числа без нажатия Enter.

Если есть вопросы, задавайте.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось попроще, чтобы  нажать кнопку `1` и получить реакцию.Я воспользовался `if()` , вместо `switch()`.

Вот код:

```
 while(p.satiety!=0)
    {
           printf("Satiety: %d ",p.satiety);
           printf("Action: \n");
    if(poll(&mypoll,1,2000))    
       {
            scanf("%d",&choice);
            if(choice==1)
                Feed(&p);
        if(choice==0)
        exit(1);
            if(choice==9)
              Instruct();
       }
          else
       {

                waitFor(2);
                Hungry(&p);
       }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Если нужен ввод именно цифры, то есть нажали кнопку <kbd>1</kbd> - получили реакцию, то без прямой работы с драйвером клавиатуры не обойтись. Где-то давал тут примеры, надо поискать.

Если же нужен простой ввод, то можно воспользоваться таймаутом в [select()](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=select&category=2&russian=). Как-то так:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define WAIT_TIMEOUT    10  /* seconds */

int main()
{
    while( 1 ) {
        struct timeval timeout = { WAIT_TIMEOUT, 0 };
        fd_set fds;
        int cc = -1;
        FD_ZERO( &fds );
        FD_SET( STDIN_FILENO, &fds );
        select( STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout );

        if( FD_ISSET( STDIN_FILENO, &fds ) ) {
            unsigned char c;
            ssize_t rd;

            /* читаем весь ввод */
            while( ( rd = read( STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1 ) ) != -1 && c != '\n' ) {
                /* но учитываем только первый введённый символ */
                if( cc == -1 ) {
                    cc = c;
                }
            }
        }

        if( cc == -1 ) {
            printf( "Ку-ку, Гриня! Кто кнопки жать будет?\n" );
        }
        else if( cc == 'q' || cc == 'Q' ) {
            printf( "Гриня хочет уйти? Жаль, но не будем ему мешать...\n" );
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf( "Гриня хороший, надавил на кнопочку [0x%02X]\n",
                    ( unsigned char )cc );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

NB! Нужно учитывать что `select()` может быть снесён каким-нибудь сигналом, поэтому если оно критично, то эти случаи надо предусмотреть дополнительно. Например, проверять сколько реально времени прошло в ожидании, или вообще таймаут отслеживать при помощи [alarm()](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=alarm&category=2&russian=), но это совсем другая история.

Comment: По умолчанию, пока новая строка не введена в терминале,  ваш код ничего не увидит. Можно вызвать tcsetattr() чтобы выключить   ICANON режим.

Comment: @jfs, а что он должен увидеть пока строка не введена? Если имеется в виду символ перевода строки, так код на то и рассчитан, чтобы ввод им заканчивался. Хотя тут немного накосячил, надо было число ловить, а не символ, но это поправимо.